# SimpleMembershipProvider vs WebSecurity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-web-api, security

I have a WebAPI project with a Repository layer.  For methods related to accounts, I'm not sure which method to use here:

```
public class RepositoryService : IRepositoryService
    {
        private readonly SimpleMembershipProvider _membership;
        public RepositoryService()
          {
            _membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
          }
```

To check if a user exists:

```
    public bool UserExists(string userName)
    {
        return WebSecurity.UserExists(userName);
    }
```

OR

```
public bool UserExists(string userName)
{
    return _membership.GetUser(userName, true) != null;
}
```

I'm wondering because in other places I think I have to use _membership (to get a specific user, for example):

```
public MembershipUser GetUser(string userName)
    {
        return _membership.GetUser(userName, false);
    }
```

But it seems odd that I have to use _membership and WebSecurity.  Is there anything "smelly" about using both?

Comment: they should have called it `LimitedMembershipProvider` or `SimpleMembershipWithConfusingUpgradePathProvider`

Comment: Membership stinks; in VS2013 too. How to reset password in System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider. **... you cannot use an existing MembershipProvider (including the Universal Providers found in System.Web.Providers) with an API that requires a SimpleMembershipProvider, including any of the calls in WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity or Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.**  [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to suggests that you are OK:

From the MSDN docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg547905%28v=vs.111%29.aspx on the `WebSecurity class`:

> Behind the scenes, the WebSecurity class interacts with an ASP.NET
>   membership provider that in turn performs the lower-level work that is
>   required in order to perform security tasks. The default membership
>   provider in ASP.NET Web Pages is the SimpleMembershipProvider class.